# How can I use mouse hover style in iview table?

Tags: javascript, css, uiview, vue.js

**Environment**

```
OS Version : ubuntu 16.04LTS , Browser Version : 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit), Vue Version : ^2.5.9
```

[**Reproduction link**](https://jsfiddle.net/2aq6rwk4/2/)

**What is expected?**

Apply mouse hover style to iview table render.
on mouse hover increase the image size.

**What is actually happening?**

No apply any style like mouse hover

Answer (score 0):

I think that `transform: scale(x)` is what you need, where x is a multiplier of your base size. Check [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2aq6rwk4/4/). [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) you can find more about scaling.